# Why does the NSBundle API have a separate "ofType" argument for the file extension?

Tags: cocoa, bundle

NSBundle's `[bundle pathForResource:@"example" ofType:@"jpg"]` is less intuitive than writing `@"example.jpg"` as in just about any other programming system. What does this API achieve (ex: are bundle contents indexed by file extension?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it's less intuitive and you can use it as you mention, both are good.
The difference is that you can use this function for other purposes. Apple's docs say that if the 'name' is an empty string or nil, it returns the first file encountered of the supplied type.

As an example, you could provide a default image on a user interface item (an NSTableView or whatever) by invoking this function with an empty name... something like 'put there the first .png image you can find'.

Answer (score 1):

You are *meant* to supply the file name (without extension) as the resource argument and the extension as the type argument. It's not clear the API does anything special (like indexing by extension) but it might (implementation detail), so it's best just to use it as intended (separate the file name from the extension when asking it to find resources).